# Propane - Putting liquid propane in a vapor canister?

Tags: propane

I want to get a flame-weeder, but it runs off vapor propane.
The tank it comes with has a vapor valve - whatever that means.

Can I go get my propane tank filled up with any propane, or do I have to specify vapor vs liquid propane?

[**This is the canister**](https://flameengineering.com/products/10-lb-vapor-withdrawal-propane-cylinder-model-c-11) that needs to be filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propane liquefies under pressure.  All propane tanks hold liquid propane.  The pressure is maintained by a small amount of the propane that turns back into a vapor in the tank.  Propane appliances draw off the pressurized vapor, which reduces the pressure in the tank, and more of the liquid vaporizes to replace it.

If you read the description on your link, you get the tank filled at any propane refiller, and it's refilled with ordinary propane.

BTW, that looks like a regular propane tank.  The thing that can vary is the connector.  If you take your weed attachment to a hardware store like Home Depot or Lowes, you're likely to find that it fits one of the standard connectors on their tanks.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused by the vapor valve and that the tool in question said vapor. I figured, I better learn before just filling the tank (with potentially dangerously wrong substances).

Comment: I'm a little nervous dealing with propane, due to inexperience and ignorance. Is there any reason why I couldn't replace that tank with this other tank: https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00KOLF1IQ/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1520116710&sr=8-1&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_FMwebp_QL65&keywords=Flame+King+YSN011+Steel+Propane+Cylinder+with+Type+1+Overflow+Protection+Device+Valve%2C+11-Pound&dpPl=1&dpID=31E-ydofoEL&ref=plSrch

Comment: That is to say, does this tank on Amazon lack anything that the original tank has, potentially making it incompatible with the equipment using the original tank?

Comment: I suspect the tanks and valves are equivalent safety-wise because of the regulations to ensure their safety for general consumer use.  As a safety precaution, though, any tank that size should be stored outside.  There are several different connectors, though, so you need to make sure that the tank connector matches the appliance connector.  Ordering an empty tank means you have to find a local refiller.  It's a lot easier to simply pick up a ready-to-go tank from the local hardware store.  When it's empty, you just swap it out with another pre-filled tank.

Comment: BTW, those tanks are a bit heavy when full.  Hopefully, the weed flamer has a long hose so you can cover a lot of ground with the tank sitting in one place.  If nothing else, you'll build some strength through this weightlifting exercise.  :-)

Comment: Another idea is to pick up a small prefilled cylinder, such as is used for propane torches (they're filled with just under 1 lb of propane), and an adapter with a connector matching the weed flamer.  They probably hold enough for flaming a reasonable-sized area (you won't get acres out of it).  Those are a lot easier to carry around.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge with me! I think it should be 14 lbs for the empty tank and 11 lbs for the propane, so about 25 lbs full, right? The original tank can be purchased with a backpack harness, but I was planning on making my own backpack and saving ~$130. Unless I'm greatly underestimating the weight (25 lbs), that shouldn't be difficult to do safely, I imagine...?

Comment: Bah, that sounded sarcastic, but was a genuine thank you for the very helpful advice. =)